# Hovering pop up message in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML form I want a popup message (similar to ToolTip) that will notify the user that caps lock is on. Currently my form checks for caps lock correctly and displays a warning in a div to the right of the text box. This div forces the page to change because it takes up some space.

Is there a way to make the div pop up as a notification cloud? By setting the z-index or some other method to make something similar to tooltip pop up when caps lock is caught?

Comment: Change DIV's position style to absolute or relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <input type="text" id="my_input" name="my_input" value="" />
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 0px; right: 0px;">
    CAPS LOCK is on!
  </div>
</div>
```

Just style it to fit your position as you wish.